# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Linux Developers CANNOT run my java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Linux Developers to write some cpp codes. As I understood it, no matter which version of Eclipse I use, it always can be used to writing some java source codes.

I did this:

- File->New>Java Project->...
- Wrote a simple "hello world". I have confidence that my hello world is correct.
- When I wrote my code, Everything went well.
- But when I right clicked my new project, I found there was no "Run as","Debug as"
- Press Ctrl+F11. It said "the selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches"
- Run->Run Configurations. I double clicked Java Application. It said "No tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication"

What should I do?

How can I run my java applications?

Comment: Why have you installed eclipse for C and C++ development if you want to write java? Try to use the eclipse made for java development instead. (And if you want to write c or c++, don't choose a new java project :}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite contrary to what you assume, eclipse isn't a Java IDE with some other addons. Eclipse is just a platform. As the [package comparison](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) shows, the C/C++ package **doesn't** come with the Java development tools.

Comment: Oh I saw it! It doesn't contains JDT!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct eclipse version is downloaded? There will be separate eclipse version available for Eclipse for java.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. But I just download this version the day before yesterday. I think it's latest. And I just don't wanna download another eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the JDT installed, then make sure you are in the Java perspective.  Either:

- Window->Open Perspective->Java (default)
- Use the perspective switching tab, usually the top-right of your code editor

You can install the JDT, if you don't have it by using:

- Help->Install New Software...

Comment: I have already opened Java perspective. And What can I fill in "Work With" in "Install New Software" window if i wanna install JDT?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install follow this link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigor if it's work. i think your eclipsec/c++ may be have a problems while install java. You can reinstall or using eclipse for java.